# Trying to set a base address in Blazor WASM from the appSettings.json file and not having much luck

Tags: c#, json, blazor-webassembly, base-address, aspnetcore-environment

I am learning Blazor WASM, and have used an example app from a book as a starting point. I have an `appSettings.Debug.json` file under `wwwroot` folder, and its contents is this:

```
{
  "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7163"
}
```

This is what my Program.cs file looks like:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using ShoppingCart;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

string baseAddress =
    builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseUrl");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ShoppingCart", client => client.BaseAddress =
    new Uri(baseAddress));

builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

And I am attempting to read the BaseUrl string like this :

```
string baseAddress =
    builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseUrl");
```

When I set a breakpoint, and get past this line, `baseAddress` variable is still set to null.

Later on, in my store.razor component, I read from a JSON file:

```
@code {
    public IList<Product> products;
    public IList<Product> cart = new List<Product>();
    private int total;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation(".GetFromJsonAsync() method about to be called");
        if (Http.BaseAddress == null)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("Base address is null");
        }

        try
        {
            const string fullProductPath = "https://localhost:7163/sample-data/products.json";
            string productFilePath = (Http.BaseAddress != null) ? 
                string.Concat(Http.BaseAddress.ToString(), "sample-data/products.json") : fullProductPath;
            products = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Product[]>(productFilePath);
            Logger.LogInformation(".GetFromJsonAsync() method was called on a previous line");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }

       
    }

    private void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        cart.Add(product);
        total += product.Price;
    }

    private void DeleteProduct(Product product)
    {
        cart.Remove(product);
        total -= product.Price;
    }
}
```

The only reason why my GetFromJSONAsync() call even works is because I am using a hard-coded uri string in case the base address is not properly set. Now, I've read in a few places that Program.cs might not be the best place to set the base address, so I am wondering if I should just try to read the appSettings.json file from my razor component. Also, I've changed the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable from `Development` to `Debug`, so that my appSettings.Debug.json file gets properly read.

```
  "profiles": {
    "ShoppingCart": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7163;http://localhost:5163",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Debug"
      }
    },
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have same problem, everything is fine in local machine, however after publishing ; while I read from appsetting.json by config DI in the services in client side, it works, but if I read and inject in HttpClient in program.cs doesn't.

Comment: Same problem here. I also wish to do this exact thing, but only from the program.cs so I can use as a Singleton, but so I don't have to hard code an api URL in without recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you have issues fetching information from appsettings.json, we do not use them in our app. Can it be because it is not sent on client side, so the file is not found? /shrug

Here is how we obtain the Base Url for the origin of the server:

> Uri uri = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);

Not sure if this can help you, but its worth a try.

Comment: That's not what the question was. They may be using an API call or many calls and the URIs may have to be changed every now and then (so you don't have to re-compile). Hard-coding something that may be changed is generally a bad idea. There are other ways of reading the appsettings.json file, however, the "correct/accepted/preferred" way is usually desired. This was done by MS, but their examples imply other settings that seem to be missing from their docs (this is one of the most asked questions and answers vary wildly). Reading settings should be standardized.

Comment: I did not say they should hardcode anything, I said that if they wanted the BaseUrl (which is typically the address the program was served from) without needing to read it from a conf file, which is what it was written, they could do so by using the method above. Now, it might not answer their needs, as stated, if what they want is a different server, but that detail is/was not clear to me.